# how to set up SVN on Mac terminal?

Tags: svn

so i know how to set up a SVN itself. I've created the folder and already have SVN itself running on my Mac. However, I'm not sure how to actually *add a repository to the folder so I can connect to the repository to start downloading*. Am I missing something here?

Comment: btw here is a list of all commands for svn in case haven't one yet: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch09.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have a server running yes?

Then just do this:

```
svn co http://server/path/to/directory/to/checkout ./repository
```

This creates a new folder 'repository' (you can name it however you want) and downloads all the stuff in 'path/to/directory/to/checkout' to it. If this contains nothing, this is not a problem but svn knows now that 'repository' is under version control.

Comment: Felix, I have been looking for that one line of code for the past two months. TY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!