# svn checkout mac os x

Tags: svn

How can I change the folder of my build in mac os x svn.
I did not install anything.

Where is svn?

I just want to download code and install for now. 
Thanks

Comment: Please rephrase this question. I don't understand at all what you mean.

Comment: Dupe http://superuser.com/questions/84259/how-to-set-up-svn-on-mac-terminal

Comment: If I e.g. enter:

svn checkout http://ratproxy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ratproxy-read-only

in my terminal on a mac os x 10.6 computer

The files are downloaded somewhere on my computer.
How can I change WHERE these files are downloaded to.
I can not phrase that simpler than that.

Comment: It will download the files to your current directory. If you don't want them where they are, then you must `cd` to a new directory (perhaps you want to *create* the new directory first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a directory in the same directory you ran the `svn` command, named `ratproxy-read-only`.  This is the same way every command-line svn client works, and is no different in OS X.  If you are not seeing this, then the checkout is not working and you need to figure out why.

Comment: I know the answer to my question now. And I tell you just to let you know how simple the answer would have been. 

I have to cd in the directory that I want the svn trunk to be downloaded to. 

I thought svn is a software where in preferences I can define a folder where it will be downloaded by default.

That was it.

Answer (score 0):

`svn` is the command for the source control program Apache Subversion. It is part of the basic software included with Mac OS X. You don't need to install anything to use though various "extensions" are available which add frills such as a GUI user interface to the command.

I suggest you either search this site or use Google to locate some basic tutorials or other instruction in how to do what you want to do.

It's not that hard to find info about Subversion. For example:
[Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)
[Apache Subversion on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)

Comment: Thanks. I have been there. But did not find that simple answer. Where can I change where the build in svn ( I know that it is build in) saves my files. Or in other words. Change the trunk?

Comment: Try looking at this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.creating or perhaps this http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate